# Memoize child component when updating parent array of objects state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to memoize my `ItemCard` component, so when I call `setItems()`, only the `ItemCard` being updated gets rerendered, is this possible?

I have a super simple component like:

```
const ItemList = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: 1, count: 5 },
    { id: 2, count: 7 },
    { id: 3, count: 2 },
  ]);

const updateItemCount = (itemId, add) => {
  const updatedItems = items.map((item) => {
    const { id, count } = item;

    if (id === itemId) {
      return { ...item, count: add ? count + 1 : count - 1 };
    }
    return item;
  });

  setItems(updatedItems);
};

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <ItemCard {...item} updateItemCount={updateItemCount} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And ItemCard looks like

```
import { memo } from 'react';

const ItemCard = memo(({id, count, updateItemCount}) => {

console.log("re-rendered", id)

  return (
    <button onClick={() => updateItemCount(id, true)}></button>
  );
});
```

The issue is when I log re-renders, they all seem to re-render after the button click

Comment: So, since you already have the code I not sure what result you're expecting, The way it is right now ir resulting in some sort of error?

Comment: Updated question -- no error, but each ItemCard seems to re-render even when wrapped in memo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `updateItemCount` in `useCallback`, since it's re-created on each render, and the `memo` sees a changed prop. In addition, add a `key` to each item you render in the `map`.

If we'll pass the `items` array to the `useCallback` dependencies, the function would be again re-created whenever the `items` changes. To avoid that use an [updater function](https://updateItemCount) when you call `setItems`.

```js
const { useState, useCallback, memo } = React;

const ItemList = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(() => [
    { id: 1, count: 5 },
    { id: 2, count: 7 },
    { id: 3, count: 2 },
  ]);
  
  const updateItemCount = useCallback((itemId, add) => {
    setItems(items => items.map(item => {
      const { id, count } = item;

      if (id === itemId) {
        return { ...item, count: add ? count + 1 : count - 1 };
      }
      return item;
    }));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <ItemCard key={item.id} {...item} updateItemCount={updateItemCount} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const ItemCard = memo(({id, count, updateItemCount}) => {
  console.log(`id update: ${id} - count: ${count}`);
  return (
    <button onClick={() => updateItemCount(id, true)}>{count}</button>
  );
});

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<ItemList />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: ahhh I had tried useCallback with no luck, but everything works with the updater function!!